# MVC 4 user get logged off quickly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, timeout, session-timeout, simplemembership, logoff

I have an MVC 4 web application that log off some users quickly. The authentication cookie seem stetted up correctly (I also setted timeout to 720 (12 hours)). I also setted session timeout on config file and in IIS. The issue seem's to happen on IE most of the time user get logged off after like 10 minutes. And as usual I can't reproduce the issue on my end.

I am wondering if an ajax call could cause the issue? Or an http header? I searched a lot about that issue and found nothing outside of basic web.config settings.

There is my configs for session, membership and authentication

```
<sessionState timeout="720"  mode="InProc"/>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider" >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms requireSSL="false" domain="dpars.com" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" name="DPARSAuth" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="720"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be losing the sessions because you're using InProc Session-State mode, which stores sessions in memory. When you use this mode, the sessions will be lost anytime the web server process restarts, which can happen for a variety of reasons.

Try changing the sessionState mode to "SQLServer", or "StateServer" and see if that solves the problem.

More information on configuring these options can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'll give it a try by changing it to StateServer

Comment: Weird I changed it to state server and now I can't authenticate at all. The websecurity IsAuthenticated stay false event if login is successful...